# Magento 2 : How to get success/error message after review post?

Tags: magento2, review, messages

When I submit review form its properly redirect back on same page and review is properly saved in admin but there is no success message.

How do I show the success message on that page and where I can set that message ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-review/Controller/Product/Post.php`

```
public function execute()
 {
   ......
   $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You submitted your review for moderation.'));
   ......
 }
```

When we want to set this message, we have two options:
*+We can use translation.*
*+We can override this class.*

**Note:** the global message may store in local storage

Comment: Yes there is a message but not displaying in front-end. Don't know whats the issue.

Comment: You have any custom this module which related to this module? When adding product to cart, the success message can show?

Comment: Which related to this module?

Comment: No, I don't have such type of module which is related to review or cart.

Comment: Or, override the template message or js `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml`?

Comment: We did all these things, We are getting all other message except review message. Also the message block of HTML are there on the page view source.

Comment: Clear your cookie and local storage?